# How do you reshape the batch size of a dataset in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I've generated a dataset, but as I work on it, I found that I will run out of memory, so I decided to batch it using tensorflow's .batch(batch_size). The problem is, this adds a batch_size dimension, so now the dimension of my dataset is [batch_size, original_dataset_size, Image Dimensions, 3(for color)]. Is there a way I can combine the batch_size and original_dataset_size dimensions, so it has the 3 dimensions required.

Layers:

```
dataset = todataset().shuffle(10).repeat().batch(batchsize)
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape = (dims*dims,3)),
  tf.keras.layers.Reshape((dims*dims,3)),
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(8),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation="softmax")
])
```

Comment: if your working with images, your input tensor should be `[batch_size, img_height, img_width, img_depth]`

Comment: I reshaped my input tensor to [batchsize, imgheight x (times) imgwidth, img_depth], but when I used the actual .batch, it added it's own batchsize, so it was [batchsize, my_batchsize,imgheight*imgwidth, img_depth].

Comment: don't use `.batch` just add the batch size in the compile function

Comment: I didn't know you could do that! Thanks very much. Is there a way I can tell if it's working?

Answer (score 0):

This is the code for using `batch_size`

```
BATCH_SIZE = 32

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape = (dims*dims,3)),
  tf.keras.layers.Reshape((dims*dims,3)),
  tf.keras.layers.LSTM(4),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(8),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation="softmax")
])

model.fit(X, y, epochs=10, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Should I remove my code with the Reshape/Flatten Layers, that were supposed to reshape it into the right shape?

Comment: I don't think so. Im not sure what your reshape function is doing since it's still the same shape. Does my code work for you?